# Critical RabbitMQ method arguments

Tags: java, rabbitmq, messaging, publish-subscribe, amqp

I'm trying to read up and understand 3 fundamental methods in the RabbitMQ Java client:

- [`Channel#basicConsume`](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.1.5/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.1.5/com/rabbitmq/client/Channel.html#basicConsume%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20java.util.Map,%20com.rabbitmq.client.Consumer%29)
- [`Channel#basicPublish`](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.1.5/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.1.5/com/rabbitmq/client/Channel.html#basicPublish%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP.BasicProperties,%20byte[]%29); and
- [`DefaultConsumer#handleDelivery`](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.1.5/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.1.5/com/rabbitmq/client/DefaultConsumer.html#handleDelivery%28java.lang.String,%20com.rabbitmq.client.Envelope,%20com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP.BasicProperties,%20byte[]%29)

These methods have several arguments that are cryptic and mysterious, and although the Javadocs do provide *some* explanation of what they are, don't really make  it clear/obvious as to what these arguments do:

- `Channel#basicConsume`

  - **consumerTag** - a client-generated consumer tag to establish context
  - **noLocal** - true if the server should not deliver to this consumer messages published on this channel's connection
  - **exclusive** - true if this is an exclusive consumer
  - **arguments** - a set of arguments for the consumer
- `Channel#basicPublish`

  - **exchangeName** - the exchange to publish the message to
  - **routingKey** - the routing key
- `DefaultConsumer#handleDelivery`

  - **envelope** - packaging data for the message

These methods, and using them correctly, are crucial to using RabbitMQ in its simplest form (basic publishing & consuming of messages to and from a queue). Until I understand what these arguments are - and what they imply/do on the server-side - I'm stuck and unsure of how to proceed with the library.

Can some battle-weary RabbitMQ veteran help a newbie like myself understand these 7 method arguments, and what they are used for? The Javadoc explanations just aren't clear enough. For example: "arguments - a set of arguments for the consumer". What?!?! Or: "exclusive - true if this is an exclusive consumer"...well what's an *exclusive* consumer?!?! Etc. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as exclusive goes, this means that only one consumer will be allowed to attach to the queue.

Comment: Thanks @sovanesyan (+1) - can I ask how you know this, or what documentation you can point me to? If that documentation explains `exclusive`, it likely also explains these other fields I need. Thanks again! And if you know of any other fields, please don't be shy!

Comment: have you had a look at the tutorials, they have lots of sample code that you can reference.

Comment: Thanks @robthewolf (+1) - yes I've read all the tutorials and these fields don't show up *anywhere*!

Answer (score 6):

Follow below two link :-

https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html

http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html

Java creates a queue in which messages may reside for at most 60 seconds:

```
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
args.put("x-message-ttl", 60000);
channel.queueDeclare("myqueue", false, false, false, args);
```

Answer (score 5):

To throughly understand the implementation of RabbitMQ you might have to go through the AMQP protocol specification and reference. In general irrespective of the language the specification should explain all the parameters

Below link explains about [consumer-tag](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.cancel.consumer-tag)

Exclusive:

Exclusive queues may only be accessed by the current connection, and are deleted when that connection closes. Passive declaration of an exclusive queue by other connections are not allowed.
The server MUST support both exclusive (private) and non-exclusive (shared) queues.
The client MAY NOT attempt to use a queue that was declared as exclusive by another still-open connection. Error code: resource-locked

Customer tag:

Specifies the identifier for the consumer. The consumer tag is local to a channel, so two clients can use the same consumer tags. If this field is empty the server will generate a unique tag.
The client MUST NOT specify a tag that refers to an existing consumer. Error code: not-allowed
The consumer tag is valid only within the channel from which the consumer was created. I.e. a client MUST NOT create a consumer in one channel and then use it in another. Error code: not-allowed

AMQP extensions to understand additional Args (Map)

http://www.rabbitmq.com/extensions.html

Example - TTL:

Per-Queue Message TTL

The x-message-ttl argument to queue.declare controls for how long a message published to a queue can live before it is discarded. A message that has been in the queue for longer than the configured TTL is said to be dead. Note that a message routed to multiple queues can die at different times, or not at all, in each queue in which it resides. The death of a message in one queue has no impact on the life of the same message in other queues.

The server guarantees that dead messages will not be included in any basic.get-ok or basic.deliver methods. Further, the server will try to reap messages at or shortly after their TTL-based expiry.

The value of the x-message-ttl argument must be a non-negative 32 bit integer (0 <= n <= 2^32-1), describing the TTL period in milliseconds. Thus a value of 1000 means that a message added to the queue will live in the queue for 1 second or until it is delivered to a consumer. The argument can be of AMQP type short-short-int, short-int, long-int, or long-long-int.

This example in Java creates a queue in which messages may reside for at most 60 seconds:

```
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
args.put("x-message-ttl", 60000);
channel.queueDeclare("myqueue", false, false, false, args);
```

The original expiry time of a message is preserved if it is requeued (for example due to the use of an AMQP method that features a requeue parameter, or due to a channel closure).

Setting x-message-ttl to 0 causes messages to be expired upon reaching a queue unless they can be delivered to a consumer immediately. Thus this provides an alternative to basic.publish's immediate flag, which the RabbitMQ server does not support. Unlike that flag, no basic.returns are issued, and if a dead letter exchange is set then messages will be dead-lettered.

Per-Message TTL

A TTL can be specified on a per-message basis, by setting the expiration field in the basic AMQP class when sending a basic.publish.

The value of the expiration field describes the TTL period in milliseconds. The same constraints as for x-message-ttl apply. Since the expiration field must be a string, the broker will (only) accept the string representation of the number.

When both a per-queue and a per-message TTL are specified, the lower value between the two will be chosen.

This example in Java publishes a message which can reside in the queue for at most 60 seconds:

```
byte[] messageBodyBytes = "Hello, world!".getBytes();
AMQP.BasicProperties properties = new AMQP.BasicProperties();
properties.setExpiration("60000");
channel.basicPublish("my-exchange", "routing-key", properties, messageBodyBytes);
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer @Mouli (+1) - however it does fail to mention `noLocal`, `exchangeName`, `routingKey` and `envelope`. And although it mentions *one* of the possible `arguments` (`x-message-ttl`) it doesn't mention any others (and I'm sure there are lots). If you could provide exlpanations for all these other properties, and perhaps give me a link to all the possible `arguments` (besides x-message-ttl), I would happily give you the green check and the bounty!

Comment: For exchange name and routing key, check this is a good example. https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-09-03-part4-rabbitmq-for-beginners-exchanges-routing-keys-bindings.html